# Google Drive API web authentication PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I need to create an external php web application (PHP) to connect to Google Drive using the API. Problem is that the quick start example illustrates that the user has to visit a url to obtain an authorization code to complete the authorization.  Is there a way to achieve the authorization automatically without any user interaction. I need to basically copy an existing doc template automatically via the web application.

Comment: Probably not. You wouldn't want to log people into an external storage application without their explicit permission.

Comment: Question says: without any user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without authorization, but is possible without user interaction. Please see the Drive SDK documentation sections on [domain delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) and [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts). Service accounts is likely what you need.

Comment: Google Docs SDK uses basic authentication. Is there any way to access a user's Docs content (i.e. a spreadsheet) via the Drive API, if the user provides their credentials? Sounds like this scenario is not supported. I'd like to use a REST API rather than the Java or other SDK's to access (download) a spreadsheet as CSV on behalf of a user. This is for a rich desktop client, not web or mobile platforms.